# Openshift Websocket custom domain

Tags: node.js, websocket, cors, openshift

I've recently changed my openshift default domain myapp.rhcloud.com in www.myapp.com with a custom ssl certificate. The config works perfectly well until the web page ask the server for a websocket connection. I use node with socket.io and websockets enabled

I first tried:

```
io.connect(www.myapp.com:8443/...)
```

But this return an error.

So I set back the socket connection url to:

```
io.connect(myapp.rhcloud.com:8443/...)
```

But I get this error:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://www.myapp.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Is there a way to allow websocket connection via a custom domain on Openshift ? Or, do I need to set up cors?

**EDIT**
I left socket.io prefix the websocket url I do not pass the protocol to socket.io

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, WebSockets use something like this (wss instead of ws for secure)

```
wss://www.yourapp.com:8443
```

Make sure you setup openshift with your domain alias

https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1096-how-to-setup-an-alias-for-your-application

Comment: There was a question about this two weeks ago on here about this. Port 8000 and 8443(???  Can't remember ) are the ones you need to use.

Comment: Port 8000 is for unsecure websocket port 8443 is for secure.

Answer (score 0):

When I log to https://www.myapp.com:8443/socket.io/1/ in Chrome, I get the error

```
Identity not verified
```

which is not the case on https://www.myapp.com... after few tests and searchs I think that this error is due to the websocket preview environnement on openshift. Source (https://www.openshift.com/blogs/paas-websockets):

> Update: There is one more known complication. When using our
>   preview-deployment of WebSockets with HTTPS and WSS protocols, you
>   will face self-signed certificate. That is because this environment is
>   only temporary to give you insight into upcoming features. Once we
>   move the new routing layer to standard ports 80 and 443, i.e. we move
>   WebSockets support into production, the certificates used will be
>   signed and valid as they are with current deployment.